# JAVA: ArrayIndexOutOFBoundException while reading imported txt

Tags: java, arrays, exception

I'm a beginner, I have got a txt file that user will imported into java, I'm going to read txt file line be line then set variable base on each line and add them to the current record

```
    public void importTXT() {
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    fc.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
    fc.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);
    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
            "TEXT FILES", "txt", "text");
    fc.setFileFilter(filter);
    int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(CollectionFrame.this);
    String[] numstrs = null;
    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File importedFile = fc.getSelectedFile();

        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(importedFile);
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                numstrs = sc.nextLine().split("\\s+"); // split by white
                                                        // space
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
        // add new collection
        Collection newCollection = new Collection(numstrs[0]);
        allRecord.addCollection(newCollection);

        // add art consignment information
        String consignmentName = numstrs[3];
        String description = numstrs[4];
```

I received a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` at the second last line

`String consignmentName = numstrs[3];`

The content of the text file is like:

```
Richman’s Estate Collection
5
ART
Water Lilies
A superb piece in great condition
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: It means array **numstrs** has less than 4 elements. Try to use **numstrs.length**

Comment: What is `Collection newCollection = new Collection(numstrs[0]);` supposed to be doing? Do you have your own type called `Collection`? because `Collection` in `java.util` is an interface

Comment: first check if `numstrs.length>4`

Comment: you should use a debugger

Comment: you know by putting it outside the loop you are using the last line only and trying to use that. Check the last line when you split by spaces will not have 4 elements in it.

Comment: @Rustam you should be checking for numstrs.length>3 actually as OP says String consignmentName = numstrs[3]; its this line where he gets AIOBE.

Comment: @almasshaikh Not I agree with Rustam as you will just propagate that error to next line.

Comment: Edit your question to include the text file data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:
you are currently reading all lines and replacing each time the value of `numstrs`
so when you leave the loop, you just got the value of the last line in it.
i think you want to save ALL lines - see below.
END EDIT

you should use an arraylist.

like this:

```
ArrayList<String[]> numstrsList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File importedFile = fc.getSelectedFile();

        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(importedFile);
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                numstrsList.add(sc.nextLine().split("\\s+")); // split by white
                                                        // space
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
}
```

you can catch the values of your arraylist with:

```
for(int i=0:i<numstrsList.size();i++){
    String[] oneLineStrArray = numstrsList.get(index)
    //do something 
}
```

you should post the text data, otherwise we cant help you about the OutOfBounds error.
Also, i am wondering how you can instantiate a Collection.

Answer (score 0):

As previous comments already has suggested, the file obviously does not contain the information in the form you expect. 
I suggest that you add som error handling to it after the scanner read.

```
if (numstrs.length < 5){
  ///TODO: add some handling here, exception or error dialog
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, first go through [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/)

Check `numstrs` length before you try to access index value(s). You can do

```
String consignmentName = null, description = null;
if (numstrs.length >= 4) {
    consignmentName = numstrs[3];
}
if (numstrs.length >= 5) {
    description = numstrs[4];
}
```

Also, as pointed out by one of the comment - `numstrs` will always have the values returned by the last line.